# GAE cursors and inequality filter

Tags: google-app-engine, cursor

From https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Limitations_of_cursors :

> *Cursors don't always work as expected with a query that uses an inequality filter or a sort order on a property with multiple values.*

Does it mean that all query with inequality filter don't support cursors? Or the sentence is referred to query with inequality filter on property with multiple values?
e.g. Will a query like this one support cursors:

`"... WHERE prop > 5 && prop < 10 "`

Comment: Did you ever discover an answer to this one?